# How do increment value while it being declared inside function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a small issue where i'm trying to increment/decrement the buttons in x steps this is all dynamic dependant on what ever the quantity step is, my code works fine when its increments of one because i am just using ++ there is no scope issue

I've tried a few things but no much luck i can't really declare it outside of the function as there is multiple input boxes and i'd need to do some sort of mapping to know which one relates to which input.

I know what the issue is its because of scoping im defining a variable inside a function but its not a simple thing to do it outside of it any other solutions to get past this without defining it outside ?

When i had it like this this.$refs[codeForRef][0].value++ it worked fine and would increment by one

```
increment: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var codeForRef = e.srcElement.id;

  var test = parseInt(this.$refs[codeForRef][0].value, 10); //the value of the qty
  test += this.dyQty //whatever it needs to go up in
 },
```

Comment: Very unclear about what you want to achieve. Could you give a complete example please ? If you just want to use test var outside the function why don't you call anotherone with test as parameter ?

Comment: It is difficult to help because your question is not clear. Are you trying to increase the value of test after setting it? Each time you call the increment method test would be reset to the parseInt value before it is increased by this.dyQty

Comment: @Chuksy, yes im trying to set it then increment it then reset it back to what the new value is so it could be like 1,3,5,7 test will keep being updated to whatever the new value is,

Answer (score 0):

what i understood from your question, this should work for you.

```
increment: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var codeForRef = e.srcElement.id;

  var test = parseInt(this.$refs[codeForRef][0].value, 10); //the value of the qty
  test += this.dyQty //whatever it needs to go up in
  this.$refs[codeForRef][0].value = test;
 }
```